# Can't login to SQL Server after joining domain

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I installed a SQL Server 2008 on a machine and created a database on it.  Subsequently, the machine that this was installed on was added to a Windows domain and it appears the original local user account that Server Server was install on was renamed or deleted.  Now, I'm unable to connect to the database using a domain administrator, newly created local administrator account, or the local system account.  When I attempt to expand the database in SQL Server Management Studio I get the error "The database  is not accessible. (Object Explorer)".  Is there any way I can get access to the database?  I want to somehow just make a copy of the .mdf file and recreate it in Management Studio and then just overwrite the newly created one with the copy but I suspect this will maintain the permission issues that I have now.  Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: So you can connect to the SQL instance, but can't get into a specific database?

Comment: Correct.  When I try to expand the one database that I have I get the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into Windows with the old username, but prefix it with the computer's name.

For example:

`PCNAME\Username`

If that doesn't work, let us know and we can help with the next step.

---

If you can connect to the SQL instance, can you do so as Administrator? If so, all you have to do is change the owner of the DB. Right-click on the database, go to Properties, then Files, and change the owner there.

Comment: Thanks but the old user may have been deleted.  I'm still investigating whether it was just renamed or deleted altogether.  I assume if it was just renamed I should be to login as the renamed user and everything should work but if the user was deleted is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can double-check which Windows user account currently owns the database?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Joining a domain doesn't rename or delete local user accounts.

Comment: @joeqwerty - it may have been done as a part of IT policy.

Comment: @joeqwerty - correct, but as part of the join the local account was either deleted or renamed.

Comment: I can't go in as Administrator either.

Comment: You need *some* Administrative rights to get back into the instance, otherwise you're reinstalling SQL Server.

Comment: @Josh Is your SQL instance using mixed mode authentication?  Do you not have the password to anything that has sysadmin privileges?

Comment: It is using Windows authentication only.  I can create a local admin account but it still can't seem to access the database.  I'm assuming this is because SQL Server can't find the owner of the database or something?

Comment: More likely the local admin group is not necessarily a sql admin, see big yellow box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280562.aspx

Comment: @SqlACID - Thanks for that link, that looks to be very relevant to my issue.  It sounds like the warning of being locked out is exactly what happened.  I wonder if I reinstall the instance of SQL Server using the new domain user and simply reuse my .mdf database if that would resolve my problem?

Comment: @Josh - reinstalling SQL is what I suggested yesterday.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I'm going to coordinate with the user on site and I'll update this accordingly.

Comment: It looks like the issue was resolved with a combination of getting a proper local administrator account added (apparently the end user didn't quite know what he was saying when he told me he tried using a local admin account previously and it didn't work) and reinstalling SQL Server.